# For which intervals $[a, b]$ in $\Bbb R$ is the intersection $[a, b]\cap \Bbb Q$ a clopen sub set of the metric space $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that if we take $a$ and $b$ to be rationals, the intersection of the interval with $\Bbb Q$ wouldn't be open and I know that if we take $a$ and $b$ to be irrational numbers, since irrational numbers are non-terminating, for each decimal point of the irrational number we get a rational number so we can open infinitely many balls for these decimal points and the intersection will be open subset of $\Bbb Q$. But, yet I don't get why this subset is also closed and therefore clopen. Also, I'm not sure what will happen in the case where we have a combination of rational and irrational number for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Recall what it means for a set to be closed. One straight forward definition is that it’s complement is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topology that you are using on $\Bbb{Q}$ is the subspace topology: a subset $X$ of $\Bbb{Q}$ is defined to be open iff there is an open subset $Y$ of $\Bbb{R}$ such that $X = Y \cap \Bbb{Q}$. From this it follows (by looking at complements) that a subset $X$ of $\Bbb{Q}$ is closed iff there is a closed subset $Y$ of $\Bbb{R}$ such that $X = Y \cap \Bbb{Q}$.

Now consider $X = [a, b] \cap \Bbb{Q}$. If $a$ and $b$ are both irrational, then we have $X = [a, b] \cap \Bbb{Q} = (a, b) \cap \Bbb{Q}$, so that, by the above, $X$ is clopen, i.e., both open and closed. If either of the endpoints $a$ or $b$ is rational, then $X$ cannot be open, because any open subset $Y$ of $R$ such that $X \subseteq Y \cap \Bbb{Q}$ contains the rational endpoint, and hence contains an open interval around the rational endpoint, which must include points outside $X$, so $X \neq Y \cap \Bbb{Q}$.

I'll leave it to you to think about when $X = [a, b] \cap \Bbb{Q}$ is closed if one of the endpoints $a$ or $b$ is rational. (Hint: if the other end-point is irrational, then you can apply the above reasoning to the complement of $X$.)